# The criterias to select peak detector capacitance and resistance

Tags: capacitor, frequency, time-constant

[image]

edit: diode is replaced with 1n4148

While designing such a peak detector, what should be the approach of choosing C and R values? Which specs of the detector will be based on them? I assume their values will be depending upon the frequency of incoming signal, and related to time constant of RC network. But, I need some better understanding.

Comment: Do you know how to choose the reservoir capacitor in a half wave AC power rectifier? Unless you’re interested only in frequencies less than a few hundred Hz, don’t use the 1N400x series of diodes.

Comment: @Andyaka so I should go with a fast-switching diode like 1n4148? And no, I don't know even what a "reservoir capacitor" is.

Comment: You should find some good google info on power rectifiers and choosing capacitor values. It’s exactly the same principle. Yeah I know you want a direct answer but....

Comment: 1N4148 is a good choice for anything sub tens of MHz.

Comment: @Andyaka thanks, I will look into them. My frequency of interest is 1-2 kHz, so 1n4148 will do the job then.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/100518/rc-time-constant-and-diode-detector